# AJAX https and SSL verification error

Tags: ajax, ssl, https

I have a page that loads a div via AJAX. The AJAX POST call is made in https from a page with the protocol also https.

If I visited the page being loaded into the div directly, there are no SSL issues. If I visit the parent page before loading the div, there are no SSL issues. The error only occurs when I click a link to load the content inside the div. Suddenly, there is an error with the SSL Cert. In firefox I get the following info: "Connection partially encrypted"

What's partially encrypted? The page is fetched via https, the parent is https, both have no problems on their own...

I don't get it.

Comment: Something is being called with the HTTP protocol. Have you run Fiddler/Firebug?

Comment: The TamperData FireFox addon (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966/) might also be helpful.

Comment: can you post your code for ajax call?
Also if you try fiddler to check all your http(s) request/response you might able to find the unintentional http page call which is the most likely cause of firefox message:Connection partially encrypted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@durilai:

Figured it out. There was a loading image being used during the ajax call that used the http protocol. It didn't appear because it loaded so quickly. Found it in the javascript.

::shakes head::

Comment: Wow. I just had this same issue. If you're displaying an image in a success response (like me) or something similar, make sure your image url has https!

Herp Derp